# Bash replace special character '

Tags: linux, bash, debian, string, replace

All the questions and answers i already read are not my solution. So, all i want to do is to replace the special char `'` in bash.

This works:

```bsh
A="abc"
B="${A//[b]/x}"
```

But this does not work:

```bsh
A="a'b"
B="${A//[']/\'}"
```

Also, i have tried:

```
B="${A//[']/\\'}"
B="${A//[']/\\\'}"
B="${A//[']/\'''}"
B="${A//[']/'\\''}"
```

But `B` keeps to be `a'b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way works:

```
A="a'b"
B="${A//\'/\\\'}"
```

Two notes:

1. The `[]` are unnecessary when only one character is inside of them
2. You need to escape `\` and  `'` inside of the substitution.